# How can I fix a build error with @bazel_tools//tools/android:databinding_annotation_processor

Tags: bazel

I downloaded the Bazel "Build an Android App" tutorial from:

https://bazel.build/start/android-app

and modified the targetSdkVersion to 33 and it built fine with Bazel.

I then switched the MainActivity to use AppCompatActivity and integrated external dependencies using rules_jvm_external with bzlmod, following directions from:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/blob/master/docs/bzlmod.md

I'm now getting:

```
ERROR: /home/maru/.cache/bazel/_bazel_maru/ffa24f764f8fce22a35440e17ba7441e/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/BUILD:446:6: no such target '//external:databinding_annotation_processor': target 'databinding_annotation_processor' not declared in package 'external' defined by /home/maru/android/examples/android/tutorial/WORKSPACE (Tip: use `query "//external:*"` to see all the targets in that package) and referenced by '@bazel_tools//tools/android:databinding_annotation_processor'
```

### Update 2023-11-30

I've revisited this starting from scratch and Bazel's "Build an Android App" builds fine until I enable bzlmod:

1. Add a .bazelrc containing `common --enable_bzlmod`
2. `mv WORKSPACE WORKSPACE.bzlmod`
3. `touch MODULE.bazel`

Then I get the above error relating to databinding, my use of AppCompatActivity was a red herring. Is this a known issue that bzlmod and Android builds are currently (using bazel version 6.4.0) actively incompatible?

Comment: databinding is not very well supported by the android rules, are you able to use compose instead? https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/main/android/jetpack-compose

Comment: also, i don't think databinding is part of the tutorial, so it might be helpful to post how you're setting up databinding

Comment: I'm not intentionally using databinding. The only change I've made is to use AppCompatActivity with the needed maven dependency (@maven//:androidx_appcompat_appcompat).

Comment: I updated my answer below. Basically, the immediate error about databinding is fixed in Bazel 7.0, but there is one other error but there's a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

databinding hasn't been updated to work with bzlmod, it requires a `bind()` in the workspace:

```
bind(
    name = "databinding_annotation_processor",
    actual = "//tools/android:compiler_annotation_processor",
)
```

and a target in `tools/android/BUILD` in the workspace (or wherever the bind points to):

```
java_plugin(
    name = "compiler_annotation_processor",
    generates_api = True,
    processor_class = "android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@bazel_tools//src/tools/android/java/com/google/devtools/build/android:all_android_tools",
    ],
)
```

and bzlmod doesn't support `bind()`.

Can you use Compose instead? https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/main/android/jetpack-compose

---

Update

This particular issue is fixed in bazel 7.0.0 with https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/f4fcb422adf1a33fe687cfe9d23d5fa0f74551fc as part of https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/issues/97

Bazel 7.0.0 hasn't been released yet, but if you have bazelisk installed you can do:

```
USE_BAZEL_VERSION=last_rc bazelisk  build //src/main:app --enable_bzlmod
```

However there are still some things that need to be fixed, e.g. you'll run into:

```
ERROR: no such package '@@android_gmaven_r8//jar': The repository '@@android_gmaven_r8' could not be resolved: Repository '@@android_gmaven_r8' is not defined
```

This can be worked around by adding the dependencies to the local workspace:

1. Make sure there's a `BUILD` file in the root workspace
2. Create `android_extensions.bzl` and add the dependencies:
   (Based on [`android_extensions.bzl`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/aa7012154cafa833d48c4c4ced5a51a18c629335/tools/android/android_extensions.bzl)):

```
# Copyright 2022 The Bazel Authors. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Module extension to declare Android runtime dependencies for Bazel."""

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive", "http_jar")

def _remote_android_tools_extensions_impl(_ctx):
    http_archive(
        name = "android_tools",
        sha256 = "2b661a761a735b41c41b3a78089f4fc1982626c76ddb944604ae3ff8c545d3c2",  # DO_NOT_REMOVE_THIS_ANDROID_TOOLS_UPDATE_MARKER
        url = "https://mirror.bazel.build/bazel_android_tools/android_tools_pkg-0.30.0.tar",
    )
    http_jar(
        name = "android_gmaven_r8",
        sha256 = "57a696749695a09381a87bc2f08c3a8ed06a717a5caa3ef878a3077e0d3af19d",
        url = "https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/r8/8.1.56/r8-8.1.56.jar",
    )

remote_android_tools_extensions = module_extension(
    implementation = _remote_android_tools_extensions_impl,
)
```

3. Add the following to `MODULE.bazel`:

```
remote_android_extensions = use_extension(":android_extensions.bzl", "remote_android_tools_extensions")
use_repo(remote_android_extensions, "android_gmaven_r8", "android_tools")
```

This should all be fixed in a future minor release of Bazel 7.

Comment: As originally mentioned, this is just Bazel's Build an Android App tutorial, and all I added was a Maven dependency for AppCompat. Is this expected to implicitly require databinding now?

Comment: When I add your suggestions to my workspace I get a new error: ERROR: /home/maru/.cache/bazel/_bazel_maru/ffa24f764f8fce22a35440e17ba7441e/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:58:19: every rule of type cc_toolchain_alias implicitly depends upon the target '//external:android/crosstool', but this target could not be found because of: no such target '//external:android/crosstool': target 'android/crosstool' not declared in package 'external' defined by /home/maru/android/examples/android/tutorial/WORKSPACE

Comment: that's strange, i didn't see that error in my testing. are you using a cc_library or have an `android_ndk_repository` in your workspace file?